# Simultaneous equations and XOR

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, boolean-algebra

I've just finished some homework on cryptography.  I have the right answer, but I think it's more from luck than skill.

(I'm trying to phrase this without breaching the honour code.)

$F(k,x)$ is some function that takes a key $k := \{0,1\}^5$ and an input $x:=\{0,1\}^4$.

I never know what $k$ is, however I have three examples of inputs and outputs.

i.e.,

1. $F(k,a)=a'$
2. $F(k,b)=b'$
3. $F(k,c)=c'$

(In the question I have concrete values for $a$, $b$, $c$, $a'$, $b'$ and $c'$.)

Given this, I have to find $d'$ for $F(x,d)$.

I have done it, and got the right answer like so:

I noticing that $a \oplus b \oplus c = d$, so I tried the following:

$d' = F(k,a) \oplus F(k,b) \oplus F(k,c)$

$\therefore$

$d' = a' \oplus b' \oplus c'$

Given I know what $a'$, $b'$ & $c'$ this is solvable.

Where I'm struggling is *why*.

$ F(k,a) \oplus F(k,b) \neq F(k \oplus k,a \oplus b)$

$ F(k,a) \oplus F(k,b) \neq F(0,a \oplus b)$

Which is, unfortunately, how I solved the problem.

So... Is there any generic rule for XORing functions like this?

Comment: What do you know about $F$?

Comment: @FabioSomenzi I know the whole algorithm.  I think I might be pushing my luck is I posted it though.  Effectively though, it's an `if` statement.  `if value = 0 then do nothing else append 1 to output`.

Comment: @FabioSomenzi I don't _think_ there's anything really special about the algorithm though.  I know I can craft algorithms whereby for some values the $F(a \oplus b) = a' \oplus b'$.

Comment: I appreciate your concern and I don't want to nudge you in the direction of pushing your luck.  So, one generic answer is that systems of equations in which we use XOR can be solved by Gaussian elimination.  Does it help?

Comment: @FabioSomenzi Thanks for the prod.  I don't know what that is (yet), but I'll have a look and see if it might the right way.  Thanks.